# trying to use (isset) with html form and php, error no index found

Tags: php, html, forms, undefined, deprecated

this is my first time posting on the server.
I am in the middle of learning PHP and in the video I copied it word for word while learning, this is what I wrote:

```
<?php
session_start();

require('DatabaseObject.php');
require('databaseVars.php');

$database = new DatabaseObject($host, $username, $password, $database);
    
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_POST['login']) {
    $username = $database->clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = $database->clean($_POST['password']);
        
    $result = $database->query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `password` 
                                FROM `Users` 
                                WHERE `username` = '$username' LIMIT 1");
    
    try{
        if ($database->num_rows == 0){
            throw new Exception ("User does not exist.");
        }
            
        $user = $database->fetch($result);
            
        if(md5($password) != $user['password']){
            throw new Exception ("The username and password combination cannot be found.");
        }
            
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['id'];
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

echo "<h3 style = 'text-align:center'>ArenaScape</h3>";

if(isset ($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    echo "Welcome to ArenaScape!";
    
}else{ 
    echo "<form action='./' method='POST'>
        Username: <input type='text' name='username'/><br />
        Password: <input type='password' name='password'/><br />
        <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login'/>
    </form>";
}
?>
```

Usually I would handle forms in http and $_POST the 'login' from html to php...
I was being shown this way of doing it, and my 'submit' form is named 'login' but when I run the code I get the

> Warning: Undefined array key "login" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Demo\ArenaScape\login.php on line 9

At first I thought it was just a warning, but when I login I get no response to the bottom part of the php code:

```
if(isset ($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    echo "Welcome to ArenaScape!";
```

I have been trying to figure it out, but I don't know where I went wrong, so I am coming to this community hoping to find some help.

Thanks in Advance.

I was trying to make the Login Form log me into the system using PHP.
I am unsure if the code is deprecated and that's why it isn't working...

Comment: Now what _exactly_ does "when I run the code" mean? Are you talking about _after_ you have actually submitted this form? Because if not, and this code also executes when the page loads with the initial GET request - then `$_POST['login']` will of course not be set. You should simply warp this, in your first if condition, into an isset as well.

Comment: Your script is still quite likely open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: And wrapping the MYSQLI_ extensions own OO interface in your own only causes confusion to those that follow and adds very little if anytihng

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: So the issue is the `$_POST['login']` Show us your HTML for the `<form>` do you have a field called `login` in there

Comment: To be blunt: Don't follow that video. It promotes bad practices (like abstracting the database connection in your own class) and ignores severe security practices both for making database queries and password management.

Comment: It also appears to be telling you to throw exceptions for problems which are really just validation notices, rather than fatal errors. So that's another bad idea.

Comment: The reason you get the error is because the first time this script loads and displays the form it's also checking if the `login` is true in that first condition without testing if it exists.  you should check `isset()` on that field.  I would do it like this `isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])`  you can check multiple with isset.  Another option is to add this before `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` and wrap all that stuff in it.   But I would check the fields to make sure they exist before proceeding with the form

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly for letting me know of the better encryption methods and thank you @ArtisticPhoenix for helping me with my problem...
Thank you guys so much... : )

Comment: I would guess this code is from around PHP 5.3 ish.   As other's have mentioned this is not something I would use in production.  Some things like checking the Post variable that way used to work "back in the day".  An md5 password is pretty useless, especially when it doesn't use a salt.   Basically you could break all the passwords in a weekend with a "rainbow table"...  I've actually done that when updating encryption on legacy stuff.

Comment: Alright, if you guys can help me with one quick thing in this subject.
at the bottom of the php file it has:
echo "<form action='/" method='Post'>

<input type = 'Submit' name='login' value='Login" but at the top where I had:
if (!isset($_Session ...... $_POST('login') it didn't connect the PHP isset from $POST login and html form <input name = 'login'

Sorry if that is confusing but do you guys know how I can fix this?